# Checking previous elements of array when looping through

Tags: php, loops

I have a (relatively) simple platform which handles running competitions. When calculating the results, the first placed finisher gets 20 points, second placed 19 points, and so on, down to a minimum of 3 points just for taking part.

The existing loop looks like this - results is an array of objects, ordered by finish time (ascending) :

```
        $pos = 1;
        $posscore = 20;
        foreach($results as $result) {
            
            $result->position = $pos;
            $result->race_points = $posscore;
            $result->save();
            $pos += 1;
            if($posscore > 3) { 
                $posscore -= 1;
            }
            // Other, unrelated, code removed
        }
```

The problem arises when it handles two (or more) finishers with the same finish time. The first one in the array will get a higher finish position (ie. lower number) and higher points than the second one, when the ideal outcome would be for both to get the same points and finishing position, and it then jump one

So at the moment if the 4th and 5th finishers both finish at the same time it will give :

1st / 20
2nd / 19
3rd / 18
4th / 17
5th / 16
6th / 15

when the actual outcome should be

1st / 20
2nd / 19
3rd / 18
4th / 17
4th / 17
6th / 15

How would I best go about maintaining a note of, or otherwise accessing, the previous finish times whilst iterating through the loop?

Comment: As you have it, scoring is solely dependent on the array order. But it sounds as if scoring should be based on time. So make an array with time as the index to assign score value, then look up score value by using the participants’ time as an index. But this is all assuming you have the time recorded somewhere. How is `$results` calculated and what does it contain?

Comment: $results is pulled from the database, and then sorted based on finish time, as you surmise, but each result holds everything needed to run the calculation.

That sounds like a good approach - if ordered by time, then each runner in a time bracket gets the same points and finish position, and then within the loop the points are reduced, and finish position increased, based on how many runners have already been counted. I will give it a play, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. But of course you need to change `arrived_time` to yours

```
<?php
$maxScore = 20;
foreach($results as $key => $result) {
    
    $result->position = $key + 1;
    $result->race_points = $maxScore - $result->position + 1;
    
    if (isset($result[$key-1])){
        $previous = $result[$key-1];
        if ($previous->arrived_time == $result->arrived_time){
            $result->race_points = $previous->race_points;
        }
    }
    
    if ($result->race_points <=3){
        $result->race_points = 3;
    }
    
    $result->save();
}
```

**P.S.:** It is not optimized code. But I guess, if you have only 20 items, or close to it, no need to overengineer here.

Comment: Bar a stray $result[$key-1] or two, which threw me, that does the trick, thank you. Yes, number of runners will be minimal, so I don't need to worry about optimisation.